# Leaky garage when it rains

Tags: leak

When it rains, I have two leaks in my garage.  I have had people look for this leak, but they can't seem to find it.  I don't know if it's my windows or roof. Who should I call to help me with this problem.

Comment: A roofing company?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniel.

Unfortunately, roofing companies make more money installing new roofs than they do fixing leaks. They will probably recommend a new roof.

If you roof is still in good condition otherwise, you may be better off  hiring a handyman to find your leak.

Good luck!